# Let's Advertise with Community Ads!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Now that we're in Public Beta, it's time to start thinking of how to spread the word! Let's start this Beta off strong by creating our own ads. <sub>Forgive me as a I plagiarize a [post from Internet of Things](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172/lets-advertise-with-community-ads) which was already plagiarized.</sub>

#### So what are these "Community Ads?"

Graduated sites allow the community to advertise relevant products or services within the site, using a system where the community chooses what to advertise. You can find these posts on per-site metas. Hint: these posts have the [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag!

#### Cool! What should the ad be like?

There's a few requirements for these ads. Most notably,

- They must be 300px wide by 250px tall, or double for "retina" displays
- There's a limit on file size of 150 kB.
- The image must be hosted on i.stack.imgur (the Stack Exchange image hosting service).
- Ads must be GIF or PNG (no animated GIFs).

#### What else should I know?

To facilitate easy posting to other sites, make sure that the embedded image is of the following format:

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

   [1]: http://image-url
   [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

You can also include a message as a part of your answer with your own thoughts: why you chose some of the elements, and what sites the ads could potentially be posted to. Don't forget to critique each other as well!

---

Those are the rules, now it's up to us to make it happen! Let's have fun with it!